# List disappears when phone rotated(Android)

Tags: java, android, list

In my app, in the OnCreate method, I create a list(using an add button) or I fetch it from a saved file. My function works fine and I am able to create and fetch the list until I rotate the phone(vertical -> horizontal). The list then disappears. I am still able to click the buttons on screen, but it seems I have no items in the list.Any help appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this tag in Activity tag in manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

and add this in activity code

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    }
```

in the same activity..

this happens because each time your screen orientation is changed `onCreate()` method of the Activity will be called every time

Comment: what do you mean by overriding onConfigurationChange(), as in what do I put in this method?

Comment: just like your onCreate() method in Activity there is another method called onConfigurationChange().. u should add it.. see my updated answer..

Comment: thank you. this worked well (although I have only tried it in the emulator). When I try it on my device, I will give you the feedback as well.

Answer (score 1):

[This post from developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) could help too!

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise if you would add screenSize at android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" aswell i.e 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize"